# Check whether the length of element in array equals the total no of elements in array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have an array variable `var arrays=[];`
In that `arrays` variable, `values` is an array

```
arrays = [
    { 
        _id: 1,
        values: [
           { checked: true },
           { checked: false },
           { checked: true }
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to get the counts where checked variable is true in `arrays` variable:

```
db.getCollection('details').aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$arrays" }, 
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": { 
            "istrue": {"$arrays.values"}
        }, 
        "count": { "$sum": 1 } 
    }
    }
])
```

I tried this, but didn't work

Comment: do you want all array values to be true or just one ? Something like   `db.getCollection('details').count({"values.checked":{$eq:true}})`

Answer (score 0):

The first part of your aggregation is Ok and you need to unwind again by 'values' if you want to count every checked state.

```
db.getCollection('details').aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$arrays" },
    { "$unwind": "$arrays.values" }, //add this line to make sure you consider every occurences
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": { 
            "istrue": {"$arrays.values"}
        }, 
        "count": { "$sum": 1 } 
    }
    }
])
```